# PHP: Split string based on its length

Tags: php, string-length, strlen, meta-title

I'm using 4 parts to build a meta title from my content.
Now I want to limit the meta title to 55 characters and cut parts from the title.
But I don't want to cut inside a word. Instead I want to check the length of the title and delete parts from the end until the whole title is under the limit of 55 again.

I'm using the following parts for example:

- `$product_name` = the name of the product - like **MacBook Pro** - 11
- `$product_brand` = the name of the brand - like **Apple** - 5
- `$product_action` = the name of the product - **buy online** - 9
- `$product_store` = the name of the product - **on Storename** - 9

Combined these are **41 characters**. So everything is fine.

But if I have something like this (**75 characters**):

> Surface Pro X black 64 GB, 512 GB 5G/Wifi Microsoft buy online on Storename

I want to reduce it to this:

> Surface Pro X black 64 GB, 512 GB 5G/Wifi Microsoft

Because that's the title with under **55 characters**.
I removed `product_action` and `product_store`.

At the moment I'm using a combined string and count the characters:

```
$product_title          = $product_name.' '.$product_brand.' '.$product_action.' '.$product_store;
$product_title_count    = strlen($product_title);
```

Is there an intelligent way to generate a title like that?
At the moment I'm using an if/else statement which doesn't work well.

Comment: Technically, all 4 things combined can be maximum of 52 chars with 3 spaces separate. What if words get cut if you want only till 55?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should go, it will trim your string at the nearest space character(' ') under 55 characters length.

```
$i = strlen($product_title)-1;
while($product_title[$i] != ' ' || $i > 55){
    $i--;
}
$final_string = substr($product_title, 0, $i);
```

Comment: Using OP's string "Surface Pro X black 64 GB, 512 GB 5G/Wifi Microsoft buy online on Storename", your code returns "Surface Pro X black 64 GB, 512 GB 5G/Wifi Microsoft buy". How to truncate it immediately after "Microsoft"?

Comment: That's a 55 characters long string, what if you put $i > 54 ?

Comment: It's the same if you put ```$i > 53``` or ```$i > 52```... That's not diriment.

Comment: I tried it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ffbd1a757757118b7175c1593d7184c8cafdd34a) and it truncates 'buy' with the condition ($i > 54)

Comment: Same here, that's what I said. But it truncates "buy" even with ```$i > 53``` or ```$i > 52```. So the issue i've pointed out doesn't lie in that condition.

Comment: Of course it does, it truncates the full world which index goes over 55, in this case 'buy's index starts at 52 and ends at 54, so if you want to truncate it too, you have to change from 55 to 54.

Answer (score 1):

put this before @Agnohendrix 's code

```
$product_title          = $product_name.' '.$product_brand.' '.$product_action.' '.$product_store;
$product_title_count    = strlen($product_title);

if($product_title_count > 55){
    $product_title          = $product_name.' '.$product_brand.' '.$product_action;
    $product_title_count    = strlen($product_title);
}
elseif($product_title_count > 55){
    $product_title          = $product_name.' '.$product_brand;
}
```